# get js and css of each plugin programmatically

Tags: wordpress

I want to iterate through each plugin and get its css/js name and path. I am exploring WordPress codex but only getting a way to include js and css but not getting a way to get included js and css in plugin.

I can get site js and css with following code.

```
global $wp_scripts, $wp_styles;
print_r($wp_scripts);
print_r($wp_styles);
```

But I need to fetch for specific plugin not for all. Can anyone show me a way, how I can do this?

Comment: What do you want to do with them? Why don't you look directly in the plugin's folders?

Comment: I am checking execution time and memory usage of each plugin that is why I need it.